# Get Value from XML File based on two child node values

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008, xpath

I have an xml document and need XPath expression to select node values based on two child node values.
XML File structure is:

```
<catalog>
<book id="123"> 
<title>Book123</title>
<author>Author123</author>
<genre>Genre123</genre>
</book>
.
.
.
</catalog>
```

I want to select book based on title and author. I've used this expression but it shows an exception which said this expression has some invalid token. I didn't figure it out how to solve this.
Expression is :

```
"book[title='" + txtBookTitle.Text + "' AND author='" + txtBookAuthor.Text + "']"
```

Any body help me in this regard ?

Comment: When you debug, is the generated expression what you expect it to be?

Comment: Do you *have* to use XPath here? Could you use LINQ to XML instead? That would be very simple, and would avoid you needing to worry about authors with quotes in their names etc.

Comment: @AustinSalonen: I need to get values of that book whose title and author is mentioned in expression. In fact, I used SelectNodes() Method which is called by root node. In my case, root node is catalog. So, I need to make it to extract node based on it child node values.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Well, XPath is compulsory here. Can you help me to get this via XPath ?

Comment: @Itz.Irshad: I'm afraid not. I don't know XPath well enough to suggest the *right* approach to including arbitrary values without having to worry about an author name of "O'Brian" etc. Hopefully genuine XPath experts will show up soon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
//book[title[text()='Book123'] and author[text()='Author123']]
```

Comment: Thanks Dear You did a great job.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//book[title='Book123' and author='Author123']
```

as your XPath. It might be worth checking you've trimmed the spaces on your inputs using .Trim(), e.g.

```
TextBox1.Text.Trim()
```

Comment: As you suggested, I used it. No exception but here this message is shown : Enumeration Yields No Results.

Comment: I tried the XML / XPath combo here: http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx and it highlighted the correct elements. Perhaps there's a casing issue or typo in the XML?